# I can't use Slimscroll in a very small Iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I am trying to get my code working with a small Iframe I made. The site where it has to be used is running on the Enjin network and it doesn't allow PHP so I had to use an Iframe to get the PHP to work. It now displays a loading gif while it is loading the data and that works perfectly fine.

However,
What I want is this loading gif and Slimscroll to work. I can't get these 2 to work together nor can I get Slimscroll to work. I have to use a limited HTML editor which allows the use of scripts (I believe) but following the steps I cannot get it working!

Here's my code

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#inner-content-div').slimScroll({
        height: '250px'
    });
});
</script>

<div id="loadImg" style="background-image: url(http://sander.server2.tmg-clan.com/loading.gif); 
                                    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
                                    background-position: center; 
                                    background-size: 64px 64px;
                                    ">
<div name="scroll" onload="document.getElementById('inner-content-div');">
<iframe border="0" name="iframe" src="http://sander.server2.tmg-clan.com" onload="document.getElementById('loadImg').style.backgroundImage='none';" scrolling="non></iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong? What do I need to add? the website it is running on is:
[The Brothers Production network](http://brothersproduction.net) and my code is the top bar on the right!

Please help me out!

Comment: I do not see your code running on given link.